# Problema com campo de Texto MySQL

Tags: mysql, texto

estou tendo uma dificuldade para armazenar um simples campo de texto no meu BD. Tenho o seguinte textarea:

```
<textarea class="txtarea" rows="4" cols="50" name="Text" id="txt_area_post" value="" placeholder="Insira uma descrição detalhada."></textarea>
```

Aparentemente é algo bem simples, quando eu armazeno o text no BD, ele fica tudo em uma única linha.

No BD o campo é do tipo TEXT.

Gostaria também de uma ajuda em que alguém pudesse me mostrar a forma correta de se armazenar um texto grande, com validação de espaços vazios, enfim, a forma correta de se armazenar e a solução para este erro. Fico grato pela ajuda!

Comment: Você precisa que ele mantenha os espaços vazios e quebras de linha apenas? Ou terá outras formatações como negrito e itálico?

Comment: George, eu estava com um problema muito idiota, mas porque eu mesmo fui um cabeção ahuahuah, eu estava jogando o valor do banco dentro de uma div ao invés de seta o textarea diretamente. Fiz isso e resolveu, e coloquei ele como readonly.

Comment: Ia comentar isso posteriormente, no BD é mantido os espaços e quebras de linha, mas se estiver jogando em HTML você tem que dar um jeito de armazenar as formatações de quebra dele <p><br> etc...
Acho que você mesmo pode responder sua pergunta e escolher como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Banco de Dados os caracteres de quebras de linha e espaços são mantidos, mas se estiver jogando em HTML você tem que, de alguma forma, armazenar as formatações de quebra como parágrafos ou linhas em branco:

`<p>Paragrafo de exemplo</p> <br />`

Como você mesmo colocou no cometário, o erro ocorreu por que jogou o texto no HTML, e nele o texto será impresso como "RAW Text".

Como você já descobriu o texto pode ser exibido dentro de um

```
<textarea readonly>
Seu texto aqui 
</textarea>
```

para a exibição das quebras de linha e espaços.